# Is the enum inside a class static?

Tags: c++, enums, declaration, enumerator

In the bellow, the values of **enum** inside the class can be accessed by the name of the class.(I didn't even instantiate the class!)

```
class Shifting
{
public:
  enum Value: char
  {
    UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT
  };

private:
  Value value_;
};


std::cout << Shifting::RIGHT << std::endl; // 1
```

Does this mean that enum within a class is static?

If not, how to statically declare an enum?

Comment: For something to be static, it must have a size and an address. An `enum` is just a declaration. It has no actual presence. It's like a `typedef` or a `using`  directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
enum Value: char
{
  UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT
};
```

this is a declaration of a type. It is not a data member of the enclosing class. The class has only this private data member.

```
Value value_;
```

of the enumeration data.

An enumerations declaration declares named enumerators. But they in turn are not data members of the enclosing class.

It is the same if you will declare a nested structure inside a class. For example

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        int x = 10;
    };

    B b;
};
```

Here is only one data member of the class A that is B b. The data member inside the structure declaration only provides the declaration of the structure B.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked it with sizeof (Shifting) and the value was actually 1.

Comment: @JungHyunmin It is the size of the underlined type.  It seems that compiler selected the type char to store the enumerators.